# Finding value in a range in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and have a column named `BOL`. This value is between 2.0 and -2.0. I am trying to find, once BOL value reaches up to 0, if it reaches to 1.0 in 10 rows after current row. And would like to findout in how many rows BOL reaches to 1.0 after it's value 0.

Here is the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'BOL': [-1.21, -1.35, -1.1, -0.84, -0.01, 0.09, 
                           -0.45, 0.78, 1.45, 1.78, 0.33, -0.96]})
```

Comment: should the 0 --> 1.0 in 10 rows be only once or multiple times?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. I am just trying to set the number to a new row if BOL reaches up to 0 in 10 rows

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach where we create a function that accepts an array and turns it into an iterator. If a `>=0` value if found it will run for another 10 iterations looking for `>=1` to return `True`. Else `False`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'BOL': [-1.21, -1.35, -1.1, -0.84, -0.01, 0.09, 
            -0.45, 0.78, 0.45, 0.78, 0.33, -0.96]
})


def findnextoccur(ar, n=10):
    it = np.nditer(ar)
    f = next(it)
    while f < 0:
        try:
            f = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
    for _ in range(n):
        try:
            f = next(it)
            if f >= 1.0:
                return True
        except StopIteration:
            return False

findnextoccur(df['BOL'])
```

Comment: Nice one-pass solution, +1. As a note, I believe this will work much better for a small number of iterations, i.e. `f` breaches 0 quickly. But may be expensive otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the code. So how can i add that row a new column like df['X10'] = 1 or 0 incase it doesn't reach to 1 in 10 rows?

Comment: You change the value False to 0 and True to 1.

Comment: @DonCoder You can: `df['X10'] = int(findnextoccur(df['BOL']))`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

A = df['BOL'].values

start = np.where(A>=0)[0][0]  # 5
end = np.where(A[start:]>=1)[0][0] + start  # 8

res = end - start  # 3
```

If you *expect* a result, but it is possible that there are no valid `start` or `end` indices, then you can wrap with `try` / `except`:

```
try:
    start = np.where(A>=0)[0][0]
    end = np.where(A[start:]>=1)[0][0] + start
    res = end - start
except IndexError:
    res = np.nan
```

You can then perform a simple comparison, i.e. `res <= 10`.

Comment: Yes sure, but this will fail if there is no value.

Comment: @AntonvBR, Yep, of course. We really need more info from OP. I'd wrap in a `try` / `except` if user *expects* a result.